# How does XML onClick work without having an event listener?

Tags: android, xml, events, onclick, onclicklistener

Events in Android require a listener and a handler. This is evident where we see in a Java class that there is an Onclicklistener and an Onclick method within that listener.

I'm confused with the XML Onclick method however, because it doesn't have an Onclicklistener. Are they always neccesary, or is the listener hidden in this case?

```
<Button
  android:Onclick="myMethod"
/>
```

---

```
public void myMethod(View view)
{
  //do magic here 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when the `attributes (like layout_width, onClick and so on)` are parsed during creation of the `View`, an `onClickListener` is created for this `View` if this attribute has been set in `XML`.
You can look this up [for example here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#3025) since it's open source.

Keep in mind that I was looking at the View class since `Button` extends `TextView` and `TextView` extends `View`.

To explain it a bit further: When you create a `View` via `XML`, all the attributes will be parsed. Then the `properties of the View are set according to those attributes`. You can also do this yourself when defining a `custom View`.

Answering your question simply: **Yes an onClickListener is created "hidden" behind the XML during View creation**

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between setting `OnClickListener` in Java code or in XML.
If you want to set the listener via the XML you have to implement the corresponding method in Java code.
When you're setting the listener via XML, then in parsed in `View` constructor and sets the listener for you automatically:

```java
case R.styleable.View_onClick:
        ...
    final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
        if (handlerName != null) {
            setOnClickListener(new DeclaredOnClickListener(this, handlerName));
        }
    break;
```

It will look like this.
**XML code:**

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:onClick="onClickFromXml" />
```

**Then in Java code:**

```
public void onClickFromXml(View v) {
    // your click listener implementation
}
```